# AngularJS How to restrict double/multiple click

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I know a solution for double/multi click on angularJS that disable on button click & enable it after completing ajax processing using ng-disabled. Please suggest any other best solution for handling double click in angularJS...

Our code will call ajax method on button click & will take small amount of tme to process & get data from db. We have to restrict second/ multi clicks mean while.

I don't want to allow click when ajax in progress...

Welcome Please be simple solutions rather than using ng-disabled, I am learner of AngularJS

createDialogService('ajs/common/templates/popup/config_reminder_popup.html',
   {
      title: isFrom,
      backdrop: true,
      controller: 'configRemindersCBController',
      footerTemplate: '' + action + ''
    });

```
$scope.saveOrUpdateReminder = function (reminder)
{
  if ($scope.isDisabled)
  {
    return;
  }
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
  if (!reminder.daysBeforeAfterCheckDate || reminder.daysBeforeAfterCheckDate === '')
  {
    alertService.openValidatPopup('Please enter days before expiration.', "Error", true, 'configRemindersCBController', 'Ok', 'u1_remove.png');
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
    return;
  }

  configRemindersService.isDaysBeforeAfterCheckDate($scope.objectId, reminder, function (result)
  {
    if (!reminder.selectedMessageTemplate.messageId || reminder.selectedMessageTemplate.messageId === '')
    {
      alertService.openValidatPopup('Please select message template.', "Error", true, 'configRemindersCBController', 'Ok', 'u1_remove.png');
      $scope.isDisabled = false;
      return;
    }
    else if (!reminder.selectedReminderSendOption.reminderSendOptionValue || reminder.selectedReminderSendOption.reminderSendOptionValue === '')
    {
      alertService.openValidatPopup('Please select reminder send option.', "Error", true, 'configRemindersCBController', 'Ok', 'u1_remove.png');
      $scope.isDisabled = false;
      return;
    }
    var enableReminder;
    if (result.Result === 'No')
    {
      if (reminder.enable === true)
      {
        enableReminder = 'Enable';
      }
      else
      {
        enableReminder = 'Disable';
      }

      configRemindersService.addOrUpdateReminderConfigLine($scope.objectId, reminder, enableReminder, function (remindersResponse)
      {
        var reminder = remindersResponse.reminderConfigLine;
        $rootScope.CONFIG = JSON.parse(remindersResponse.configData);
        $scope.$modalClose();
        $scope.isDisabled = false;

        _.filter(configRemindersService.getMessageTemplates(), function (msg)
        {
          if (reminder.messageTemplateId === msg.messageId)
          {
            reminder.selectedMessageTemplate = msg;
          }
        });

        _.filter(configRemindersService.getReminderSendOptions(), function (option)
        {
          if (reminder.reminderSendOption === option.reminderSendOptionValue)
          {
            reminder.selectedReminderSendOption = option;
          }
        });

        if (configRemindersService.getIsFrom() === 'Create Reminder')
        {
          configRemindersService.getReminders().push(reminder);
        }
        else
        {
          configRemindersService.getReminders()[configRemindersService.getIndex()] = reminder;
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use ng-disabled? That is pretty much the purpose of ng-disabled, to disable a button under certain conditions.

Comment: I added code above pls check Casao

Comment: If you're set on not using ngDisabled, move the state management to the configRemindersService -- that way you only need to be sure that the code there handles properly setting the variable.

Comment: And welcome the approach of using directive, if we add directive in button, it shouldn't allow multi clicks

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled is definitely the proper way to go with this -- it's a ready-made directive for disabling an object under certain conditions.

If you need to disable it without it looking disabled, you have 2 options:

1. Change the css for the disabled state to look like it's enabled.
2. Mimic this with a scope variable that only performs the actions when set.

For the second:

```
$scope.stopClick = false;

$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    if ($scope.stopClick) { return; }
    $scope.stopClick = true;
    <.. code ..>
    callback: function(data) {
        $scope.stopClick = false;
    }
};
```

This will accomplish the goal, but it's reinventing the wheel and is likely less robust than just disabling the element and restyling it.

Comment: `stopClick` does not need to be on $scope, but does need to be outside the scope of `$scope.buttonClick` but this is another workable solution to a problem that does not need solved (ng-disabled)

Comment: Yes Casao.. this is one the way & similar to my way.. but in my code hv so many terminations, if I miss any where to put   $scope.stopClick = false; it will trouble me..

Comment: You need some way to store a state. You're doing that with a variable, one way or another. You could possibly change all requests to go through a single service, which handles changing the state of that variable for you (and thus the code is only in one place).

Comment: single service is difficult to use in our case Caseo, because I have many controllers & services, especially in different files

Comment: Sorry then, I don't think you'll find what you need -- you can't prevent a second click on an object without tracking the state somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this :

Create a $scope variable

```
$scope.myFunnyPromise = null;
```

in the template :

```
<button ng-if="myFunnyPromise == null"></button>
```

Only show the button if myFunnyPromise equals null.

And in your function :

```
if($scope.myFunnyPromise !== null){

  return $scope.myFunnyPromise;

}

$scope.myFunnyPromise = asyncTask().finally(function cleanUp(){

  //clear the $scope variable
  $scope.myFunnyPromise = null;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function in `$rootScope` which contains information about whether there is an ongoing http request. Then you can use that value to disable the buttons that you don't want successive click events.

I usually use `fieldset` attribute to disable input fields while there is an ongoing http request.

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="isWaitingForServerResponse()">  //when there is an ongoing request, input fields under this tag will be disabled       </fieldset>
```

For implementing `isWaitingForServerResponse` I got help from a busy bar implementation, which shows a loading bar while there is a http request. It creates events when there is a new request and another request when it stops. So in these events I incremented a counter which holds the number of active http requests and decrement it for each http response. I haven't used it before but I guess you can also use the `$http.pendingRequests` property too for understanding whether there is a pending http request.

```
$rootScope.numberOfResponseWaitingFromServer = 0;
$rootScope.$on("cfpLoadingBar:loading", function (event) {
  $rootScope.numberOfResponseWaitingFromServer++;
});
$rootScope.$on("cfpLoadingBar:loaded", function (event) {
  $rootScope.numberOfResponseWaitingFromServer--;
});
$rootScope.isWaitingForServerResponse = function () {
  return $rootScope.numberOfResponseWaitingFromServer > 0;
}
```